# How to execute a function when the display comes on?

Tags: java, android, function, screen, repeat

I want my app to check the system battery percentage every 5 seconds and display it on a textview. However I searched for the repeating function thing and couldn't find anything.
So now I want to execute the function `getBatteryPercentage()` every time the user unlocks the phone i.e when the screen display turns on.

If someone can provide the function repeating every 5 secs code or the screen on code, please tell me.

Comment: in your app run a **service** that will continuously check for battery level and update your text view. 
ps: i didnt down vote

Comment: how to run a service??